# jupyter notebook cannot find -lpthread and -lc

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pthreads, jupyter

First question here, I'm pretty new to Python. Using Ubuntu 18.04, I've been setting up to run a new program from my lab. I had a hard time getting compilers (such a gcc) to work in the install. I finally have everything installed but cannot get jupyter notebook to open. I've been trying everything on Google for 1.5 days now to fix this. The first error is:

```
/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: /home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/celloracle_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../../libzmq.so.5)
```

I've made sure that pthread and c are installed but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Picture of the full error below. Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46euR.png)

Comment: You appear to be running a linker that you've installed in your home directory.  Presumably, you built it and the rest of GCC from source yourself (which is not so easy, so congrats).  Although this approach can be made to work, it is asking for trouble.  Instead, install the appropriate operating system packages for C-language development.

Comment: Alternatively, I see that you are running into this in an Anaconda environment.  I thought Anaconda's internal package manager, "conda", would handle installing additional packages without building them from source (for those packages available from its repository, which include the various jupyter components).  Am I mistaken there, or are you using some other mechanism for your installation attempts?